# Reduce a Multigraph with edge weights to simple graph with minimal edge weight

Tags: c++, performance, input, dijkstra

I have a shortest path problem:
Given a graph with `n` vertices, find the shortest path(as in number of edges taken, not edge weight) from vertex 1 to vertex n, if there are multiple of those paths, take the one with the least lexicographical order of its edge weights.

The Input consists of `n` and `m`, `n` vertices and `m` edges (2 <= n <= 100.000; 1 <= m <= 200.000) followed by the `m` edges.
Between 2 vertices can be multiple edges. It's my first time working with C++, coming from Java.

---

My current input/main looks like this:

```
ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
int n, m, v1, v2, w;
vector<string> outvec;
while (infile >> n >> m) {
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        infile >> v1 >> v2 >> w;
        //TODO Only add smallest edge between 2 vertices
        if (v1 != v2) {
            adj[v1].push_back(make_pair(v2, w));
            adj[v2].push_back(make_pair(v1, w));
        }
    }

    dijkstra(n + 1);

    string outs;
    while (n != 1) {
        outs.insert(0, to_string(col[n]) + " ");
        n = previ[n];
        k++;
    }
    outs = outs.substr(0, outs.length() - 1);
    outvec.push_back(to_string(k).append("\n").append(outs).append("\n"));
    for (auto& v : adj) {
        v.clear();
    }           
}
```

Where `adj` represents the adjacency list, an `array` of `vector<pair<int,int>>` to be exact.

---

After all that I'm using `Dijkstra's Algorithm` for the shortest path with the 2 metrics mentioned above. But it's still too slow for the needed cases.

My idea was, to reduce the maximum number of edges between two vertices to one, with the minimum weight of all edges before, so that Dijkstra won't need to traverse all edges between two vertices.

Is there an efficient way to achieve my goal? And is Dijkstra the way to go here?

---

So my problem is my performance in runtime, so here is my current implementation on dijkstra as well:

```
void dijkstra(int m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        dis[i] = INT_MAX;
        col[i] = INT_MAX;
        previ[i] = -1;
        vis[i] = false;
    }
    dis[1] = 0;
    priority_queue<pair<int, double>, vector<pair<int, double> >, cmp> q;
    q.push(make_pair(1, 0));
    while (!q.empty()) {
        pair<int, double> currPair = q.top();
        q.pop();
        int currVertex = currPair.first;
        double currWeight = currPair.second;

        if (vis[currVertex]) {
            continue;
        }
        else if (currVertex == m - 1) {
            break;
        }

        vis[currVertex] = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < adj[currVertex].size(); i++) {
            int nextVertex = adj[currVertex][i].first;
            int nextEdgeCol = adj[currVertex][i].second;
            int currEdgeCol = col[nextVertex];

            if (!vis[nextVertex]) {
                pair<int, int> newP;
                if (currWeight + 1 < dis[nextVertex]) {
                    previ[nextVertex] = currVertex;
                    dis[nextVertex] = currWeight + 1;
                    col[nextVertex] = nextEdgeCol;
                    newP = make_pair(nextVertex, dis[nextVertex]);
                }
                else if (currWeight + 1 == dis[nextVertex]) {
                    if (col[nextVertex] > nextEdgeCol) {
                        previ[nextVertex] = currVertex;
                        dis[nextVertex] = currVertex + 1;
                        col[nextVertex] = nextEdgeCol;
                        newP = make_pair(nextVertex, dis[nextVertex]);
                    }
                }
                q.push(newP);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

For further information on the problem look [here](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=448&page=show_problem&problem=4474).

Comment: There's a `q.push(newP)` that will add a default constructed pair if `currWeight + 1 > dis[nextVertex]`